# Google BigQuery - High-Compute queries Pricing issue from BQ UI

Tags: google-bigquery

As per GBQ documentation: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing, for High-Compute queries, where there is a UDF, user need to specifically mention the maximum billing tier.

For my project, the default billing tier is 1, but the query job (with an inline JS) I sent for processing, I did not mention any value into maximum billing tier so it should limit it to tier 1 and if any processing goes beyond tier 1 BQ UI should give an error saying something like billingTierLimitExceeded. That did not happen and query ran successfully with following stats:

```
Creation Time   Jun 13, 2017, 11:43:02 AM
Start Time  Jun 13, 2017, 11:43:03 AM
End Time    Jun 13, 2017, 11:50:51 AM
Bytes Processed 132 GB
Bytes Billed    132 GB
Billing Tier    14
```

fortunately the bytes processed and billed are not too much, so it all costed less than $10 (14*5*132/1000), but that could have accidentally caused a lot of cost if  my query would have returned too many in bytes billed.

Is this some BQ UI bug or do I have to start putting in maximum billing tier 1 every time ?

Comment: By "inline JS" do you mean with a legacy SQL UDF? Or standard SQL `CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION` statements?

Comment: the query is something like this (legacy sql )

SELECT  input1, input2, output1, output2 FROM 
JS((      // input table 
  SELECT input1, input2 
 FROM [some table]
  GROUP BY 1,2),
  input1, input2,      // input columns
  "[{'name': ‘input1’, 'type': 'FLOAT'},    // output schema
   {'name': ‘input2’, 'type': 'FLOAT'},
    {'name': ‘output1’, 'type': 'STRING'},
  {'name': ‘output2’, 'type': 'FLOAT'}
  ]",
  "function(row, emit){    // function 
  
// some functionality here 
// then emit 
       
  }"
)

Comment: That functionality was never part of the public documentation as far as I'm aware and I would really recommend using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/) instead.

Comment: oh, its a great functionality though, too bad it not officially supported yet :). Ok I will switch to standard sql in this use case so that I don't break the bq accidental cost barriers.